# Warum "alles" und nicht "allem" in "Deutschland über alles"?

Tags: dative

> Deutschland, Deutschland über alles

Warum wird in diesem Satz die Akkusativform verwendet und nicht die Dativ?

Soll es nicht

> Deutschland, Deutschland über allem

heißen?

Ich verstehe nicht, wie der Satz mit "alles" überhaupt grammatik ist.

Danke und bitte antwortet auf Deutsch

Comment: Auch: _Ich liebe Dich (es) über Alles._

Comment: Wohin, nicht wo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In einer Aufforderung kann eine präpositionale Richtungsangabe eine ausreichend starke Bedeutung bekommen, um ein Imperativ-Verb der Bewegung zu ersetzen, das dann sozusagen elliptisch ergänzt wird.  Vgl.:

- *Auf sie mit Gebrüll!*
- *Runter vom Tisch!*
- *Füße hoch!*

(Nebenbei: wenn nicht die Angesprochenen, sondern dritte Partizipanten die sind, die sich bewegen sollen, können diese mit *mit* ergänzt werden:

- *Weg mit dem Müll!*
- *Raus mit den Umweltverschmutzern!*

Sozusagen hortativer Gebrauch.)

*Deutschland über alles* ist insofern speziell, als es als einziges der gegebenen Beispiele metaphorisch gebraucht wird (*über alles* iSv wichtiger als andere Nationen, andere Werte, Kleinstaaterei, oder so).  *Über* steht somit im Akkusativ, weil es sich um eine solche Richtungsaufforderung handelt.

Natürlich kann man die Konstruktion auch anders elliptisch interpretieren (*[ich liebe/schätze dich] über alles* o.ä.), aber so verstehe ich sie.

*Deutschland über allem* wäre ebenfalls möglich, ist dann allerdings nicht als Aufforderung zu verstehen, sondern als Nominalphrase (im "Vokativ") mit näherer Bestimmung: *[Oh] Deutschland, das du über allem [bist], ...*, aber das kommt mir weit weniger natürlich vor.

(Den Rest der Hymne kenne ich übrigens nicht, also kein Priming in der Richtung.)

---

Darüber hinaus ist *über alles* auch noch eine feststehende Konstruktion, die mit der Richtungsangabe nahe verwandt ist.  Sie kann verwendet werden, um die Intensität bestimmter Verben (zumeist des Fühlens) als "über alle Maßen", "über alles Denkbare hinaus gehend" zu beschreiben (*ich liebe dich über alles*).  Die metaphorische Gleichsetzung einer Qualität mit einer Skala bestimmt hier den Inhalt und die Notwendigkeit einer Richtungsangabe.

Zum Vergleich: *ich liebe dich über allem* verwendet diese metaphorische Konstruktion nicht.  Es kann entweder rein lokativ bedeuten (hier schwierig), oder als Satzadverbial "insgesamt, darüber hinaus", ähnlich en. "overall".  Letzterer Gebrauch ist aber nicht ganz idiomatisch, und würde markiertere Informationsstruktur verlangen (*über allem liebe ich dich auch noch!*).

Comment: Eben nicht "an die höchste Position der Wertungen von Nationen" sondern *Ein vereinigtes Deutschland an die Stelle eines Flickenteppichs aus Fürstentümern!*.

Comment: Ah, macht Sinn. Mit der Geschichte davon ich auch nicht vertraut. Werd ich ergänzen. Aber: ich bin sicher nicht der einzige, der das kontextfrei falschlicherweise so interpretiert.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Mir ist der Sinne von "Ich liebe dich über alles" noch nicht klar. Ist das auch eine Richtungs- oder Zielsangabe? Warum nicht "über allem"?

Comment: Ich habe dazu noch was ergänzt.

Comment: Es geht aber weiter mit "über alles in der Welt." Das deutet eher auf "Über Reichtum, Gesundheit, Familie, Religion" hin als auf "über Kleinstaaterei". "Über andere Nationen wie Frankreich, Russland, ..." ist für eine schwülstige Hymne m.E. zu schlicht.

Comment: `lieben über alles` vs `lieben über allem`. Is this referring to the same "alle"? For example, I can think of "`I miss you, but above all, I love you`" (above all I do; above all things that happen), as well as "`I love you above all`" (more than I love anyone else). (It's ok if you answer in German. My comprehension is much better than my German writing.)

Comment: @SassaNF Ja, das sind verschiedene _alle_: "alle irgendwie geliebten Dinge" im Akkusativ, und "alle Handlungen im Äußerungskontext" im Dativ. Auf Englisch ist beides idiomatisch, aber _lieben über allem_ ist entweder etwas eigenartig oder hat einen antiquierten Touch. _vor allem_ wäre die bessere Übersetzung (gleiche Metapher eigentlich, aber üblicher).

Comment: Gerade diesen Satz nur grammatikalisch zu erklären, ohne auf die Geschichte einzugehen, halte ich für falsch. Vor allem scheint hier als ein Deutungsansatz auch noch die Nazi-Interpretation durch

Comment: Kann sein, aber das haben doch schon die Anderen erledigt. Und dafür fühle ich mich außerdem nicht qualifiziert.

Answer (score 9):

Als [Hoffmann von Fallersleben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Heinrich_Hoffmann_von_Fallersleben) den Text 1841 verfasste, war der [Deutsche Bund](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutscher_Bund) ein Staatenbund aber kein Staat im eigentlichen Sinne. Mit seinem Text war Fallersleben laut [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Deutschlandlied) "urging unity for the crazy quilt of German polities".

Es geht also ursprünglich darum, die Einheit Deutschlands als wichtigste Aufgabe *über alles* zu stellen - über alle anderen politischen Interessen der Fürsten und über alle regionalen Differenzen. Das wird ja auch in der dritten Strophe deutlich: Einigkeit und Recht und Freiheit ... danach lasst uns alle streben ...

*Über alles in der Welt* drückt also die Bedeutung der Einheit und ein **Hinwirken** auf diese aus und keine Abgrenzung gegen andere Nationen (was angesichts der damaligen Situation ja auch gar keinen Sinn ergeben würde).

Erst in der Nazizeit wurde das *über alles in der Welt* umgedeutet zu *über allem in der Welt* in dem Sinne, als Nation *über allem in der Welt* zu stehen, also einen **Platz** einzunehmen.

---

*Über* ist eine [Wechselpräposition](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/wechselpraepositionen.html), die entweder Akkusativ für Richtungsangaben oder Dativ für Ortsangaben verlangt. Hier ist also Akkusativ die richtige Wahl, um eine Ausrichtung auf etwas hin auszudrücken.

Comment: Danke, aber ich verstehe immer noch nicht warum die Akkusativ-Verwendung..

Comment: *Über* ist eine [Wechselpräposition](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/wechselpraepositionen.html), die entweder Akkusativ für Richtungsangaben oder Dativ für Ortsangaben verlangt.

Comment: Ich sehe auch keine Richtungsangabe.

Comment: @fdb Siehst du eine Ortsangabe?

Comment: @Olafant. Auch nicht.

Answer (score 4):

Welchen Kasus ein Verb, ein Adjektiv oder eine Präposition fordert, ist prinzipiell eine **lexikalische Eigenschaft** des jeweiligen Wortes. Das ist eine vornehme Formulierung dafür, daß man schlicht auswendig lernen muß, wann welcher Kasus steht.

Im Deutschen hat sich bei einer Gruppe von Präpositionen, den sogenannten Wechselpräpositionen, dagegen eine Regel eingestellt: im räumlichen Gebrauch bezeichnen sie mit dem Akkusativ eine Richtung, mit dem Dativ einen Ort.

Aber das heißt nicht, daß alle Wechselpräpositionen sich auf diese räumliche Bedeutung beschränken. Blicken wir auf *über*, so findet man z.B. eine **kausale** Bedeutung mit dem **Dativ**:

> und diese unsere Kleider und Schuhe sind alt geworden **über der sehr langen Reise**. [Jos 9, 13](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Josua9%2C13)

Unser aller Lieblingswörterbuch, das DWB, erwähnt eine **komparativische** Bedeutung von [*über*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=23,72,65) mit dem **Akkusativ**:

> 13) *plus. die comparativische bedeutung von über ist seit ahd. zeit geläufig und die verwendung mannigfach.*

Man vergleiche die folgende Bibelstelle

> und der do lieb hat den sun oder die tochter **über mich** der ist nit mein wirdig (DWB unter 13) d)

mit der moderneren Übersetzung:

> Wer Vater oder Mutter **mehr** liebt **als mich**, der ist meiner nicht wert [Mt 10, 37](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Matth%C3%A4us10%2C37)

Die Verbindung mit Pronomina wird im DWB behandelt ab 13) e), spezifisch *all-* unter 13) e) δ). Um nur ein Beispiel zu nennen:

> wir sehen daraus, dasz die menschen den beharrenden willen **über alles** zu schätzen wissen

Jedenfalls paßt diese Bedeutung zu *Deutschland über alles*, verstanden als *Deutschland mehr als alles*. Und genau parallel dazu *ich liebe dich über alles*, *mehr als alles*.